# Can't compile with VHDL 2008 Quartus Prime

Tags: vhdl, intel, quartus

I'm using Quartus Prime Lite Edition and I want to use unary operator *nand* on std_logic_vector like this

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity example1 is
    port( 
        BIN : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        result : out std_logic
    );
end;

architecture Beh of example1 is
begin
    
    result <= nand BIN;
        
end Beh;
```

I tried to follow [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/13.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_pro_vhdl_input_version.htm) instructions, changed **VHDL version** under *VHDL Input* in *Compiler Settings*. Still no effect and getting:
*Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at lab2.vhd(16) near text "nand";  expecting "(", or an identifier ("nand" is a reserved keyword), or  unary operator*

Comment: `nand` is an binary operator, it needs **two** operands.

Comment: @busybee binary operators like this were added to VHDL 2008 to allow reduction of binary arrays.

Comment: @Piotr Chmielewski IIRC, Prime lite does not have full VHDL 2008 support, only prime pro does. Have you checked in the Quartus doocumentation that this feature is supported? Have you also checked that the file is specified or compiled as VHDL 2008?

Comment: Prime Lite no longer has VHDL 2008 support https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/po/ss-quartus-comparison.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quartus Prime Lite does not support VHDL 2008.

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/po/ss-quartus-comparison.pdf

Comment: That's a dumb thing to charge for!

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming as "nand" requires two inputs.

From your question, it appears to me that you want to perform the bitwise nand operation on the input.

If yes, you can replace architecture as follows. I am assuming that you are familiar with the "generate for" syntax!

```
architecture Beh of example1 is 
--Signals for Storing Intermediate Bitwise Values
signal temp1:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal temp2:std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

begin
-- First level of NAND Operations

label_1: for i in 0 to 3 generate
temp1(i)<=BIN(2*i) nand BIN(2*i+1);
end generate label_1;

-- Second level of NAND Operations

label_2: for j in 0 to 1 generate
temp2(j)<= temp1(2*j) nand temp1(2*j+1);
end generate label_2;

-- Getting the Final Output 

result<= temp2(1) nand temp2(0);
end Beh;
```

Thanks,
Dr. Ray

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I saw that nand could be used with one vector only in 2008, so I asked how. Now I know that Quartus Prime Lite does not support it.